# Assistance with transpose function using Bash

Tags: bash, awk, transpose

I want to transpose a given matrix provided in a grading script. I cannot use AWK. The function must be written in Bash. I have the following code where the AWK works perfectly with the provided grading script. the non AWK script returns errors that it is not involutory or that its not the proper dimensions. all in all the outputs look similar and i am stuck on why they appear to be different to the grading script. if there is any way that someone can help convert the AWK stript to Bash not utilizing AWK.

#### Transpose 1 - one way to read file

```
DONE=false
until $DONE;
do
    read -a myLine || DONE=true
    for ((i=0;i<"${#myLine[@]}";i++))
    do
        temp_array[$i]+=" ${myLine[$i]}"
    done
done < $1

for ((i=0;i<${#temp_array[@]};i++))
do
    printf "%s\t" ${temp_array[i]} >> temp_file
    printf "\n" >> temp_file
done
```

#### Transpose 2 - Read file. will read all lines into an array.

```
while read -a myLine || [[ ${#myLine[@]} -gt 0 ]]
do
    for ((i=0;i<"${#myLine[@]}";i++))
    do
        temp_array[$i]+=" ${myLine[$i]}"
    done
done < $1

for ((i=0;i<${#temp_array[@]};i++))
do
    printf "%s\t" ${temp_array[i]} >> temp_file
    printf "\n" >> temp_file
done

cat temp_file
rm temp_file
```

Both work and appear to have the same output.

This code works perfectly with the grading script:

```
cp $1 $temp_input    #copy file to temp file named temp_input
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {a[NR,i] = $i} }
NF>p { p = NF }
END { 
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
        str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++)
    {str=str"    "a[i,j];}
    printf str"\n"}
}' $temp_input # for loop to transpose temp_input file contents
rm $temp_input
```

Expected result is a transposed matrix that is not involutory. Both results from NON-AWK code and code provided using AWK should have the same exact output. Please help.

Comment: "involuntary" is an unusal error message. What is the exact wording used? Do you mean "involutory"? You provide two bash scripts that you say work, so what is the problem? You should provide some test data that demonstrates the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Spell check changed the word. We’ll update later. No the bash scripts don’t work hence the error. It’s the AWK script that works. AWK is not permitted hence the issue. No test data provided otherwise I would have.

Comment: Just to be clear the 2 bash script will transpose the matrix with a tab delimiter. However the AWK was written to do the same. When I run the grading script with the AWK script I get full points. When I run it with the NON AWK script the grading script returns an error and no points are given.

Comment: You say `No test data provided otherwise I would have`, so how to you test your scripts?  We do not care what the assignment says, you must provide something so we can test our solution before proposing it.  Then you say both bash scripts do not work, yet later say they do not.  Confusing!

Comment: The thing is that ... **awk** is the better language for this transposition.  As a glue language **sh** (_bash_) is a nice hackishly flexible language... but once we start implementing something like programming lower level tasks or structured text processing... well it is “intentionally” a pain.

Comment: Thanks, I agree it’s a pain. I made the argument that AWK was better and got shut down. I agree with what you said and did the same using -a, NF, and NR. I’ll try it again :/

Comment: Nic, By they work means at the surface level the output looks correct. however the check indicates that they are involutory. when i use the AWK script they do not trigger that error. however at the surface both are similar. hence they work. Now when i say they dont I am saying that it is not acceptable to have the error that says the output is involutory. if they were the exact same output no error would be triggered and hense this post would not exist.

Comment: to continue my last comment...  "Also i stated that AWK is not permitted hense why i provided it and asked for assitance sinse that output does not result in an error and full credit is given. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So rewrite the awk script to bash. I used `read -a` to read a single line into an array. Then you just count number of lines `NR` and count the number of fields `NF` and duplicate the awk script.

Because you didn't provide any data to test, I needed to create some myself, hope you include some example input and example output in your next question.

I used associative bash arrays to duplicate the `a[1,0]` indexing in bash, like in awk.

```
cat << EOF > file
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
EOF

echo -------------- awk
< file awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {a[NR,i] = $i} }
NF>p { p = NF }
END { 
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
        str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++)
    {str=str"    "a[i,j];}
    printf str"\n"}
}'

echo ------------ bash

# same in bash
# note indexes start with 0
declare -A a
NR=0
while IFS=$' \t' read -r -a line; do
  for i in ${!line[@]}; do
    a[$NR,$i]="${line[$i]}"
  done
  ((NR++)) ||:
done < file
NF=$i
for ((j = 0; j <= NF; j++)); do
  str="${a[0,$j]}"
  for ((i = 1; i < NR; i++)); do
    str+="    ${a[$i,$j]}"
  done
  printf "%s\n" "$str"
done
```

will output:

```
-------------- awk
1    5    9
2    6    10
3    7    11
4    8    12
------------ bash
1    5    9
2    6    10
3    7    11
4    8    12
```

Tested and written in [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/MeekMundaneGames).

Comment: This code does not work as you stated. the output is: <br> 3    3    3
7    7    7
11    11    11

Comment: [No. It does work, as provided in repl.it online bash](https://repl.it/repls/MeekMundaneGames). If it doesn't, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ex. code it in an online service and provide the link. Without smallest reproducible example that exposes the "does not work as you stated" behavior that you mentioned, I can only play guess games.